# sql deadlock in transaction scope

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have transaction scope and I would like to:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
   1) Insert row into table1
   2) Select rows from table1  (incuding inserted row in step 1)
   3) Insert another row into table1 
   4) Select rows from table1 (incuding inserted row in step 1 and 3)
}
```

Is there any chance to get a sql deadlock in those operations? I'm usig Entity Framework for Db work. I'm not sure about this.

Thank you,

Have a nice day.

Comment: Do you mean 'Is it possible for this routine to generate a sql deadlock by itself', ie without any-one else accessing the database? Or do you mean 'Is is possible for a sql deadlock to occur if two (or more) users are running this routine at the same time'?

Comment: a mean deadlock by itself.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problems with this.

The inserts may lock other users out, or even lock other transactions made by yourself, but it does not lock you from doing anything in the **same** Sql transaction.

Comment: thank you. So there is no way to get deadlock inside same sql transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible for a deadlock for occur.

If `SQL Server` chooses to escalate locks required by `INSERT` operations to page or table level and this scenario occurs:

```
Transaction 1         Transaction 2
INSERT INTO page1
                      INSERT INTO page2
                      INSERT INTO page1
INSERT INTO page2
```

then the two transactions will deadlock and one of them will have to be rolled back.

Comment: In my opinion there is one transaction defined by transaction scope. EF framework also created transaction during inserting. But I was thinking that this "small" transactions will be commited immediately(and tables will be unlocked). So where exactly there will be two transactions in time? Thank you.

Comment: @Quassnoi There is only one transaction here. All of his queries are run concurrently within the same transactionScope.